# How do you run APK application files on Apple Silicon Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, apple-silicon, android

I want to run a few Android applications on my Mac computer somehow. However, I cannot find a way to.

Things I tried:

- BlueStacks, doesn't run on Apple Silicon.
- Andy, but the download page returns an 404 error.
- BluestacksX, but this only works with pre-installed apps.

I also looked in the App Store but didn't find anything there.

So which options do I have to run Android apps on Apple Silicon?

Comment: I'm not sure how to reconcile that BlueStacks 4 for Mac supports M1 and M2 and your report that it won't run on Apple Silicon. Could you edit this a bit further to explain if you're looking for help with a specific package or just general recommendations (of which I bet someone will say - try BlueStacks 4 for macOS)  - https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000735272-Introducing-BlueStacks-4-for-macOS

Comment: @bmike The page you link to starts with "Introducing BlueStacks X for Mac! Play Cloud Games on various Mac devices (including M1/M2) and enter a new era of gaming!", this is about BlueStacks X (the cloud offering). Where on the page did you find anything about BS4 running on Apple Silicon? Given that BS4 requires Virtualbox I doubt it will work.

Comment: PS: I can't even start the BS4 installer on my M1 Mini...

Comment: "BlueStacks 4 is not supported on Mac computers older than 2014, Mac computers with M1, M2 and M3 chips, macOS 12 Monterey, macOS 13 Ventura and macOS 14 Sonoma." See: https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025866511

Comment: Maybe answer: Wait for BlueStacks 5 (currently Windows only) on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks @nohillside I totally missed it was a cloud offering. I appreciate the help understanding this.